# iOS 8.4 doesn't update constraints on uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm  making a very simple `collection view`. I want an `image` in each `cell` that make half width of the cell. I modify the frame of the cell with

```
(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have only 4 constraints on my image (I made them on the storyboard):

- Leading space to cell leading = 0
- Top space to cell top = 0
- Bottom space to cell bottom = 0
- Right space to cell center X = 0

The things is it looks fine on the storyboard, but don't work in real.
Here an image : [image]

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: have you set the content mode of the image view as scaleTofill

Comment: No I used Aspect Fill

Comment: Did you override `layoutSubviews` in the `UICollectionCellView` ?

Comment: No I did not. I only use dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier and change the background color of the cell.

Comment: using layoutSubview you can change your cell size...If you want the image exactly half size of cell then you can add two imageviews (or view) & then set then constraint as equal height & equal width

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Scale To Fill Mode on your UIImageView

Comment: It works, but I loose the original aspect. So it's not a perfect solution. Why Aspect Fill doesn't work ?

Comment: You can't keep aspect ratio of image and force it to be half of the cell size at the same time